# Any ideas why my IOS upload via Application Loader fails with this error message if I use an adhoc provisioning?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, provisioning, adhoc

I am a total noob with macs so apologies if I use the incorrect terminology.

When I upload the an IPA file to iTunesConnect using the Application Loader with an adhoc profile I get this message:

> ERROR ITMS-90163: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements.  The
>   entitlements in your app bundle signature do not match the ones that
>   are contained in the provisioning profile.  The bundle contains a key
>   that is not included in the provisioning profile: 'beta-reports-active
>   in Payload/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxx'."

yet when I upload it with an app store provisioning it works fine.

I have set up an adhoc certificate and installed it to xcode - it shows up in my in my provisioning details window.  I have two device ID's set up for ad hoc testing in the developer centre and presumably all other details such as app id etc are correct as it works with the app store provisioning.

Are adhoc builds not supported by Application Loader?

Comment: You *can't* upload a binary with `adHoc` profile attached. You should have three different profiles, 1. Development - by using you're able to do debug while testing in your device. 2. Production - by using you're not able to debug but can test in your device. Mostly, we will use it when we want to test APNS. 3. AppStore - by using it you are able to upload your binary to your store.

Comment: @Hemang is correct, you can't upload to the app store with an ad hoc profile, you should instead create an App Store profile.  As a side note, the Ad Hoc profiles are almost useless now that Apple has limited side-loading and now requires use of TestFlight through iTunesConnect to do testing.

Comment: thanks @hemang and Bek.   I think that confirms what I was thinking.  The use of Testflight negates the need for adhoc I guess.  Not a problem I suppose - it was more out of curiousity having spent a few nights scratching my head trying to navigate through the maze of apple app signing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please remove all provision profile and certificates from your key-chain(certificates) Xcode (provision profile).

2.Uncheck associated domains from your Apple Developer Account(AppID section from Left Panel) and from Xcode(from capabilities tab) then reinstall provision profile and certificate.

I think this will help.

Comment: thanks for your response.  I think from the other comments I'll just ignore the use of adhoc from now and just use Test flight for testing.